# Why do I get a lot of packages when I run`npm install`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package, npm-install

[image: these are the many packages]

[image: and this is my package.json]

I wonder if it's about my global package.json or something?

Comment: Look at your `package.json`...

Comment: I've show my package.json……

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`npm install` command will install packages listed in devdependencies as well as dependencies.
You are having 5 modules in devdependencies they will be installed. More then this these 5 modules will also have their own dependencies so they will also be installed.

For example if "`mocha`" will have 10 other modules listed in devdependencies/dependencies then this 10 modules will also be installed.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

when you run npm install, it installs all the packages listed in package.json

Hope it helps!

Comment: no……my package.json shows I've never want to install so many packages